# Copy everything from a source directory to a new directory Delphi EX7

Tags: delphi, file-copying, movefileex

My end goal is to copy all the relevant files from one folder to another. So e.g. we have `C:\Users\Tool\Desktop\test\oldStuff`. In the folder `oldStuff` we have more folders as well as some *mp3*,*mp4* and *txt* files.

Now what I would like to do is copy all the *mp4* files that are smaller than a GB to `C:\Users\Tool\Desktop\test\New_Stuff_Less_than_a_Gig`, and the *.mp4* files that are bigger than a GB to `C:\Users\Tool\Desktop\test\New_STuff_Bigger_than_a_Gig`.

I though is this would be pretty easy but I was wrong. So far have this, didn't worry about file type for now so just made it `*.*`

```
 procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
   f: TSearchRec;
   Dir: string;
 begin
    if not SelectDirectory(Dir,widestring(Dir),Dir) then   Exit;
    FileMode:=0;
    if FindFirst(Dir+'\*.*',faAnyFile,f) = 0 then
    repeat
         try
          if (f.Attr and faDirectory ) < $00000008 then
          CopyFile(PChar(Dir+'\'+f.Name),PChar
 ('C:\Users\Tool\Desktop\test\new\'+f.Name),false);
         except
          on e: exception do
            ShowMessage(E.Message);
         end;
    until findNext(f) <> 0
 end;
```

which will copy anything in the folder that is selected but it doesn't copy anything from the folders within the selected folder. E.g. if we have `C:\Users\Tool\Desktop\test\oldStuff\movie.mp4` it will copy the `Movie.mp4` file but if we have `C:\Users\Tool\Desktop\test\oldStuff\movies\Movie.mp4` it won't copy the `Movie.mp4` file. I though I could just do something like this

```
CopyFile.size < 1000 (PChar('C:\Users\Tool\Desktop\test\oldStuff\*.*'+f.Name),
                   PChar('C:\Users\Tool\Desktop\test\new_Stuff\'+f.Name),false)
```

or even just

```
CopyFile (PChar('C:\Users\Tool\Desktop\test\old\*.*'+f.Name),
                   PChar('C:\Users\Tool\Desktop\test\new\'+f.Name),false);
```

but it didn't copy anything.

Comment: SHFileOperation or IFileOperation. Stand on top of the system.

Comment: FWIW, there are many many mistakes in your code. Starting with mixing GUI code and file copying in one function. Continuing with an absence of error checking, an erroneous attribute test and a badly places exception handler.

Comment: Hi David  , thanks will Google both shortly and see what I come up with, thanks for the heads up.@DavidHeffernan

Comment: I rolled back your edit. You can't change the entire question after you've received answers to it. If you now have a different question about a totally different approach, create a new question and ask it there.

Comment: Remove the `*` in both places where you use `SameText`. They're not in my code in my answer, and they don't belong in yours either. `*.txt` is not a valid file extension, and `ExtractFileExt` returns a **file extension**. `*.txt` will **never** be the same text as `*.txt`, because *they're not the same text*.

Comment: Or better yet, update it to use the current version of my code, which removes the need to use the extension inside that test at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example (done in XE7) that will do what you want. You'll need to modify it to suit your needs, obviously; it has hard-coded path information and file mask (*.png) and uses a constant to decide whether the file is large or small.

It's based on this sample directory tree:

```
D:\TempFiles
  |--\Test
  |-----\A
  |-----\B
  |--------\SubB   
  |-----\NewFiles
  |-------\Large
  L-------\Small
```

It finds all of the *.png* files in *D:\TempFiles\Test* and it's subfolders, and copies the ones equal to or larger than 10KB to *D:\TempFiles\NewFiles\Large* and the ones smaller than 10KB to *D:\TempFiles\NewFiles\Small*.

You'll need to add `IOUtils` and `Types` to your implementation `uses` clause.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aLargeFiles: TStringDynArray;
  aSmallFiles: TStringDynArray;
const
  LargeSize = 10 * 1024;
  SourcePath = 'D:\TempFiles\Test\';
begin
  aLargeFiles := TDirectory.GetFiles(SourcePath, '*.png',
                   TSearchOption.soAllDirectories,
                   function (const Path: string; const SR: TSearchRec): Boolean
                   begin
                     Result := (SR.Size >= LargeSize);
                   end);
  aSmallFiles := TDirectory.GetFiles(SourcePath, '*.png',
                   TSearchOption.soAllDirectories,
                   function(const Path: string; const SR: TSearchRec):Boolean
                   begin
                     Result := (SR.Size < LargeSize);
                   end);
  CopyFilesToPath(aLargeFiles, 'D:\TempFiles\NewFiles\Large\');
  CopyFilesToPath(aSmallFiles, 'D:\TempFiles\NewFiles\Small\');
end;

procedure TForm1.CopyFilesToPath(aFiles: array of string; DestPath: string);
var
  InFile, OutFile: string;
begin
  for InFile in aFiles do
  begin
    OutFile := TPath.Combine( DestPath, TPath.GetFileName( InFile ) );
    TFile.Copy( InFile, OutFile, True);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The OP asked to copy files from subfolders as well, but this code does not recurse onto any subfolders.

Comment: @Remy: Rewrote to use `TDirectory.GetFiles` and recurse subdirectories.

Comment: Hi Ken , not sure why but the {CopyFilesToPath} is bouncing back as a undeclared identifier. will play around with it a bit and try add it to what I have already. @KenWhite

Comment: It's right there in the code I posted - you can read it yourself. You need to add it as a form method (click on it and hit Ctrl+Shift+C, or add it to the form's declaration manually.

Comment: Hi Thanks Ken , I added it manually. now it says the 's' in OutFile := ExtractFileName(s); is an undeclared identifier .

Comment: There was just a small mistake using the wrong variable. I just corrected that and changed all to use the tools from IOUtils

Comment: Hi Rufo, thanks but it doesn't copy =( ... I will do more googleing tomorrow. thanks for all the help guys learnt a lot.@SirRufo

Comment: @Chewy: The code **does** copy. I tested it before posting it, and it correctly copied the files in my test directories just as I explained in my answer. If it's not working for you, you did something wrong.

Comment: @Chewy: My code copies fine, if you remove the two errors you introduced, as I've explained in my comment to your question.

Comment: Hi Thanks, Ken works like a dream, thank you so much for the help, I don't have the rep top give you the answer. I feel a bit ashamed that I got stuck on so many easy questions and needed help with such small things. am busy looking up all the functions you called.

Comment: Actually, you do. You can accept answers to your own question, even with zero rep. In fact, you've [done it before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811784/reading-the-last-line-in-a-tmemo-in-delphi).

Comment: Thanks Ken, I accepted your answer and I edited my post back to the original question. sorry about changing it. @KenWhite